# Conditional jQuery validation based on custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'd like to enable/disable buttons on key up change conditionally based on a custom data attribute that matches between an input and a button. I've solved it with just one input, but it seems that when I add another one in the mix, the buttons don't seem to enable.
Furthermore, I **have a hunch** that it's because of .each() but I can't put my finger on it.

[Here's the CodePen I've tried and failed on](https://codepen.io/robcsaszar/pen/ZELRrvq)

```
var validation = $('[data-validation]');
var validate;

validation.on("change keyup", function (e) {
  let validated = true;
  validation.each(function () {
    let value = this.value;
    validate = $(this).data('validation');
    
    if (value && value.trim() != "") {
      validated = false;
    } else {
      validated = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
  
  if (validated) {
    $('[data-validator=' + validate + ']').prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $('[data-validator=' + validate + ']').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to only run your validation code for the input that was changed. As opposed to what you have, which is to run for all inputs.

To get the input that actually changed, you can utilize the `.target` property of the event object passed to the event handler.

Alternatively, if you remove the `validation.each()` entirely, it also works. That is because `jQuery` sets the value of `this` to be the DOM element (not a jQuery-wrapped element) that actually triggered the event.

```
var validation = $("[data-validation]");
var validate;

validation.on("change keyup", function (e) {
  let validated = true;
  let value = this.value;
  validate = $(this).data("validation");

  if (value && value.trim() != "") {
    validated = false;
  } else {
    validated = true;
    return false;
  }

  if (validated) {
    $("[data-validator=" + validate + "]").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("[data-validator=" + validate + "]").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I actually did try removing the `validation.each()` but for some reason it didn't work. I must've messed up something else. Thank you for the explanation and the quick answer!